# When is it not appropriate to use inttypes.h?

Tags: int, c99

C99 and later provide the `inttypes.h` header which defines portable type definitions for integers of specific widths. This is a stronger guarantee than e.g. C's standard `int` being *at least* 16 bits wide, and `long int` being *at least* 32 bits wide.

Assuming a project which can work with C99 or later and not requiring ANSI C89 specifically, is there any use case where using `inttypes.h` and the types defined therein would be inappropriate, especially since at first glance this library seems like a near-universal improvement over C's basic `int` types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with the C99 types is that although their sizes are defined in platform-independent fashion, their behaviors aren't.  For example, given `uint16_t a=3,b=4,c=5; int x= (a > b-c)`, some implementations would be required to yield 1 (since 3 > -1) but others would be required to yield 0 (since 3u < 65535u).  In many cases, one can get around such limitations by explicitly masking off the results of operations, and in many cases writing code as e.g. `(a > (uint16_t)(b-c))`, `(a > ((int)b-c)`, or `(a > ((int32_t)b-c)` [depending upon what one actually wants to compute] would make the intention more clear.

On the other hand, sometimes integer promotions can manifest themselves in weird ways.  In deciding whether short unsigned types should promote as signed or unsigned int, the authors of the C89 observed that on most then-current implementations, signed and unsigned arithmetic will behave identically outside a few specific contexts, *even in cases that go beyond the range 0..INT_MAX*, but some implementations seek to exploit the fact that the Standard doesn't actually *require* that.  It may not seem that something like:

```
unsigned mulMod65535(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) { return (x*y) & 0xFFFF; }
```

should have any side-effects, but if gcc knows that e.g. y==65535, it will use that to propagate back the fact that x "can't" be greater than 32768.  Interestingly, present versions of gcc would seem to refrain from such an assumption if the function returned `uint16_t`, but I'm unaware of anything that promises future versions won't be more aggressive.